# vb.net Windows login prompt

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms, authentication

I want before the vb.net application can start a windows login prompt.

Is it possible in vb.net with Windows Forms that appears a windows login prompt before running the application?

Comment: This question is programming 101, please research first before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a login form and show it from the Myapplication class on the startup event and write your codes there or select the login form  as startup form from the project properties.

Read this topic to show Myapplication class [Topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2bys999(v=vs.100).aspx)

Here a Login Tutorial using vb.net [Topic](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/form/LoginT.htm)